# Javascript y firebase, tengo un problema ya que estoy tratando de configurar el botón eliminar pero, me está generando un error, el cual no he podido

Tags: javascript, botón

Tengo una base de datos en firebase, y cargué los registros en una tabla a través de JavaScript en una aplicación web, al momento de presionar clic en el botón eliminar me genera un error y no me elimina el registro que seleccioné, el error lo genera específicamente al en `ref()` que está en la siguiente línea: `firebase.database().ref('students/${uid}').remove()`. Si yo le quito `/${uid}` me elimina todos los registros pero necesito eliminar solo el registro seleccionado. Agradezco su ayuda.

```js
const deleteStudent = (Uid) => {
    firebase.database().ref('students/${uid}').remove()//ESTA ES LA PARTE QUE ESTÁ GENERANDO EL ERROR, NO ELIMINA EL SEGISTRO SELECCIONADO 

}
```

**Código**

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async(e) => {

    await studentRef.on('value', (students) => {
        studentsTable.innerHTML = ``
        students.forEach(student => {
            let studentData = student.val()
            studentsTable.innerHTML += `<tr>
            
            <th>1</th>
            <td>${studentData.Documento}</td>
            <td>${studentData.Nombres}</td>
            <td>${studentData.Apellidos1}</td>
            <td>${studentData.Apellidos2}</td>
            <td>${studentData.Grado}</td>
            <td>${studentData.Jornada}</td>
            <td>${studentData.Rh}</td>
            <td>${studentData.Acudiente}</td>
            <td>${studentData.Direccion}</td>
            <td>${studentData.Zona}</td>
            
            <td>

            <button class="button is-warning" id="${studentData.Uid}">
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" > </i>
            </button>
            <button class="button is-danger" id="${studentData.Uid}">
                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt " > </i>
            </button>

        </td>
        </tr>`
            const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.is-danger')
            deleteButtons.forEach((button) => {
                button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                    deleteStudent(e.target.dataset.id)


                })
            })

        })
    })
})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El error te dice que la referencia que estás enviando a firebase es inválida y eso es por que estás usando comillas simples en lugar de backticks para construir esa referencia. Es decir, al usar comillas simples lo que estás enviando es `students/${uid}` y lo correcto sería `students/12345`. Eso lo logras con el uso de los templates literals que te permiten incluir expresiones dentro de un string, pero para que funcione correctamente debes usar backticks ``, así que solo debes sustituir las comillas simples por backticks:

```
const deleteStudent = (uid) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`students/${uid}`).remove()
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Efectivamente era eso.